# Cannot invoke getItemId() on the primitive type boolean

Tags: android, xml, boolean

I am new to android development and I have searched most of Menu option examples on the web. I am trying to handle a simple click event using "getItemId" and I get the following error :

> Cannot invoke getItemId() on the primitive type boolean.

Here's the code :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu)
{
    // Handle Selection of Menu Items
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case(R.id.refresh):Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
        case(R.id.info):Toast.makeText(this, "Info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break; 
    }
return true;
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

not this:

```
switch (item.getItemId())
```

but:

```
switch(menu.getItemId())
```

The reason this fails is just as the error says.  Booleans are primitives, not objects.  I am assuming somewhere above this excerpt is the line `boolean item;`.  If you did a switch on a boolean the only possible cases would be `true` and `false`.

Instead of `item`, use `menu` - this is the menuItem passed to this method as a parameter.

And unfortunately, I don't know if *.getItemId() will work on a `menuItem`.  I haven't tried it.  If it doesn't, let me know, and I'll help ya find another way.